# Loading data into mysql from a file on live server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to load data into mysql from a .dat file.

This is how I tried it in my local host:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'H:/websites/project1/www/sql/myfile.dat' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE airports 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(apid, name, city, country, iata, icao, y, x, elevation, timezone, dst, tz_id);
```

Its working for me and populating mysql table with the data from my file. But my problem is when I running this query on live server I can not load the data and its getting an error message.

This is how I tried it on live server:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'tmp/myfile.dat' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE airports 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(apid, name, city, country, iata, icao, y, x, elevation, timezone, dst, tz_id);
```

**NOTE:** my `tmp/` folder inside the website root directory.

This is the error I am getting:

```
 MySQL said:
#1045 - Access denied for user 'laksiri'@'localhost' (using password: YES) .
```

Comment: Give a folder to permission for read/write.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta, Yes I have already given the right permission to the folder.

Comment: both permission( read/write ).not just a write to user 'laksiri'@'localhost'.

Comment: Do you have 'file' privilege in mysql? Because that is required to execute a load data infile command.

Comment: @Shadow, How I check do I have `file` privilege?

Comment: Use show grants command.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta, Do I need to give read/write permission to tmp folder?

Comment: @KaushikMaheta, I have given that permission to `tmp/` folder.

Comment: @Shadow, this is the result of `show grants` - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `laksiri\_test`.* TO 'laks...`

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709105/importing-a-database-into-phpmyadmin-1044-access-denied-for-user

Comment: You do not have grant pivilege and apparently you cannot grant it to yourself either. You need to ask whoever operates the live mysql db to grant this privilege to you, else you need to find another solution to import a file into mysql.

Comment: If this is a shared hosting environment, then probably this request will be denied.

Comment: @Shadow, Yes I am using reseller hosting package and its operating by myself .

Comment: If you operate mysql yourself, then you have access to one of the root accounts that can do practically everything. If not, then you do not operate the mysql yourself. If you are not on a vps, then you do not operate the db.

Comment: @Shadow, I have created this database in my primary account. And when I creating this DB and user I added the privileges to this user. But I couldn't find `file` privilage there.

Comment: @Shadow, I got a solution with importing my file to the server. Its working now.

Comment: @Shadow, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then login with your primary account and execute the grant comnand Ed suggested in his answer. Of course, check if the username is correct (the host part as well, not just the name!!!).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your grand permissions .Try  this query in your MYSQl server to grand permission .Replace DB_Name as your database

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON `DB_NAME`.* FROM 'laksiri'@'localhost'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `DB_NAME`.* TO 'laksiri'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I don't think that this will fly in a production server. Well, it should not.

Comment: I can get this error - `#1044 - Access denied for user 'laksiri'@'localhost' to database 'laksiri_test' `

Comment: @user3733831: check this link this may helps you http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/mysql-1044-access-denied-error-message

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant file to the user:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

"FILE" is only assigned as a GLOBAL permission.

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'laksiri'@'localhost'
```

To check your existing grants do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='laksiri'
```

Comment: I can get this error when I run your select query `#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'laksiri'@'localhost' for table 'user'`

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you had a super user account access. Shadow is right, if you run:

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'laksiri';