# 'root' @ 'localhost' denied access to database 'mysql' even though I have already logged into phpmyadmin using the root username and password

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am using HostGator and have logged into PHPMyAdmin, but am having issues upload a .sql file from a localhost to the new database I created. The error that comes up is this:

[image]

So I decided to go back and check my privileges for my root user. I type in `SELECT user ()` which comes back with ajohnson@localhost. I also do `SELECT current_user ()` just to be safe and it still comes back with ajohnson@localhost. Then I type in `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';` and it comes back with this error message:

[image]

which is the exact same error I get when I try and import my .sql file. I have tried changing the import file from this 
Database: `wordpress-test`

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `wordpress-test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `wordpress-test`;`
```

to this Database: `ajohnson`

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `ajohnson` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `ajohnson`;`
```

I also tried typing this into my command line `grant all privileges on wp.* to user@localhost identified by 'PASSWORD'; flush privileges; \q`, but I got the same error message.

I have tried changing, commenting out, and removing these areas of my file completely, as well as creating new databases, but all are giving me the same error.

Comment: can you please show your database file?

Comment: As in the .sql file I am trying to import or the database I created?

Comment: I figured it out! It was all explained here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709105/importing-a-database-into-phpmyadmin-1044-access-denied-for-user)

Answer (score 0):

First you can check if you have access to create multiple database: as suggested in this post
[importing a database into phpmyadmin #1044 - Access denied for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709105/importing-a-database-into-phpmyadmin-1044-access-denied-for-user)